# Change Text Color Every X Seconds JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to javascript. I am writing this website and I want to randomly change the color of the logo periodically whilst the mouse hovers over it. So it goes color1, then waits x milliseconds, then color2 and so on until the mouse is not hovering over it anymore. So far I am only able to change the logo to one randomly chosen color. Furthermore I think the way I am using 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' seems pretty confusing and inefficient, is there a better way to use them?

My code (I've left only the essentials)

```
!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function listen() {
                var logo = document.querySelector('.logo-btn');
                logo.addEventListener("mouseover", event => setTimeout(changeColor(event), 500));
                logo.addEventListener("mouseout", event => resetColor(event));
            })

            function changeColor (event) {
                var colors = ["#ff3300", "#fbfb32", "#99ff33", "orange", "magenta", "#3399ff"]
                var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                var logo = event.target;

                logo.style.color = color;
            }
            function resetColor (event) {
                var logo = event.target;
                logo.style.color = "black";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="x">
                    <button class="logo-btn">Logo</button>
                </a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

````
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}

.header-logo {
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 40px;
}

.logo-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-align: bottom;
}
```
Thank you very much!
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had done it pretty much right. All you needed was to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Also, you need to store the interval in a variable and clear it on `mouseout` so that the text does not keep changing the color.

```js
let interval;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function listen() {
  var logo = document.querySelector('.logo-btn');
  logo.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {interval = setInterval(()=>changeColor(event), 500)});
  logo.addEventListener("mouseout", event => resetColor(event));
})

function changeColor(event) {
  var colors = ["#ff3300", "#fbfb32", "#99ff33", "orange", "magenta", "#3399ff"]
  var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  var logo = event.target;

  logo.style.color = color;
}

function resetColor(event) {
  var logo = event.target;
  logo.style.color = "black";
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-logo {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-logo">
      <a href="x">
        <button class="logo-btn">Logo</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: THANK you so much! Works as I intended it to. Although why does it seem to take longer in between some colors than others? Does that have to do with the manner in which setInterval works? Once again, thank you for the quick and effective reply.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure but `setInterval` is known to cause performance issues when it is used with short delays especially on Old CPUs. Might be because of it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this...

```
let colors = [1,2,3],
element = document.querySelector('whatever-your-logo'),
colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor(){
    //set color
    element.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    //change to next color
    colorIndex++;
   // if it's last color then back to first colorIndex
   if(colorIndex >= colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
}

//Interval
let priod = 1000; //in ms
let interval = setInterval(changeColor, priod);

//done...
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. I get an error message: 'cannot read properties of null (reading style) at changeColor).

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function can be a solution for your problem.

You set mouseOver variable on 1 when mouse is over, and on 0 when mouse is out.
You also call setColor on mouseover and check if mouse is over with mouseOver flag.

Now you call setColor that set a new color every time it's called based on selected variable

```
var logo = document.querySelector('.logo-btn');

logo.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {setColor(event); mouseOver = 1});
logo.addEventListener("mouseout", event => resetColor(event));

var colors = ["#ff3300", "#fbfb32", "#99ff33", "orange", "magenta", "#3399ff"],
    selected = 0,
    mouseOver = 0

function setColor(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[selected]

    if(mouseOver){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(colors.length > selected + 1){
                selected = 0
            }
            else{
                selected ++
            }
            setColor(e)           
        }, 500)
    }
}

function resetColor(event){
    selected = 0
    mouseOver = 0
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[selected]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor for the answer but it is not working for me.

Comment: The color changes to red and stays there, even after removing mouse (mouseout).